# Icone Android abre navegador com website

Tags: android, ios, url

Estou criando uma página responsiva e gostaria de saber se é possivel criar um app instalavel para android/ios que seja somente um ícone que abra o navegador com o endereço da minha webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja um app instalável pela Play store, pode criar uma app nativo (ex: pelo Android Studio) que conterá apenas uma tela (Activity). Essa tela terá um elemento WebView que carregará sua página. Está pode ser cacheada no dispositivo, para que o aplicativo também funcione offline, se isso for necessário/possível. 
Também é possível criar um atalho na laucher do Android que leva para a página no navegador web.